# Interactive between classes

Tags: java

I am not sure if the title is accurate. I have several classes like Tv and I want to use all of them in only one class. Is it possible to call the methods in Tv in another class? If so, do I need to revise the constructor in class Tv? (TS is an interface).

```
class Tv implements TS{

    private String v;

    public Tv(String v){
            this.v = v;
    }

    public void open(){
            System.out.println("open");
    }

        public void volume(String v){
        ...
        }

}

public class TvSet{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Tv t = new Tv("+");
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
public class RunTv {
    Remote r = new Remote("+");
    Tv t = new Tv("+");
    t.open();
}
```

The IDE reminds me "`identifier expected after this token`." Should I modify `Tv` or `RunTv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is already answered by Owl and Roddy of the Frozen Pea, but to summarize: Yes you can call methods in another class as long as they are public and you have an instance of the class containing the method.

For your other problem with the "`identifier expected...`" error, you should change `RunTv`.

You cannot call `t.open()` outside a method block. If you changed it to something like this:

```
public class RunTv {
    public void openNewTv()
    {
       Remote r = new Remote("+");
       Tv t = new Tv("+");
       t.open();
    }
}
```

Then whenever you call the `openNewTv` method it will create a new instance of `Remote` and `Tv` and it will then call the `open` method in the `Tv` instance. To call `openNewTv` you could create an instance of `RunTv` in your `main` method like this:

```
public class TvSet{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Tv t = new Tv("+");
        RunTv runTv = new RunTv();
        runTv.openNewTv();
    }
}
```

If you do not want to create a new instance every time you have to open a new `Tv` you could make the method static, which means it will not belong any instance, but rather the class itself (To understand these things better, you should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html))
You can make the method static like this:

```
public class RunTv {
    public static void openNewTv()
    {
       Remote r = new Remote("+");
       Tv t = new Tv("+");
       t.open();
    }
}
```

Now you can call `openNewTv` without having to create an instance of `RunTv` like this:

```
public class TvSet{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Tv t = new Tv("+");
        runTv.openNewTv();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If the method definition has `public` in it that means you can call those method after creating `Tv` object in other class.

`public` is an access modifiers, However the public methods can only be called after creating an object of that specific class. like this,

```
Tv tv = new Tv("A", "B");
tv.open();
```

It would be great to read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) as well, it will guide you how to write Java program step by step.

Comment: I meet some new questions and I have revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your methods are defined as `public` -- like in your example, `public void open()`, you can call those methods on a TV object from within another class.

So in your `TvSet` class, in your main method:

```
public class TvSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tv t = new Tv("+", "+");
        t.open(); // this is valid
    }
 }
```

Also, if both `TvSet` and `Tv` are in the same package, you can use default access modifier on your method instead of `public` -- eg. `void open()` instead of `public void open()`.

If `Tv` had a method like this:

```
private void close() { 
    System.out.println("CLOSED"); 
}
```

Then you could *not* do this:

```
public class TvSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tv t = new Tv("+", "+");
        t.close(); // this WILL NOT work
    }
 }
```

This is because the method is `private`, and private methods can only be called within that class.